# Flask: api call downloads excel sheet, need to store in folder

Tags: python, file, python-requests

The following url downloads an excel spreadsheet

```
http://www.bocsar.nsw.gov.au/Documents/RCS-Annual/bluemountainslga.xlsx
```

via flask code I want to call that url, and save the spreadsheet to a folder

So far I have

```
    r = requests.get('http://www.bocsar.nsw.gov.au/Documents/RCS-Annual/bluemountainslga.xlsx')
```

But need help moving the spread sheet to a downloads folder inside the project. The folder structure is.

```
App
 +static
 +templates
 main.py
 +downloads
   |__ move file here
```

Comment: Have you tried writing to the location you want to after getting the content?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Do you know how to create a file in Python? Do you know how to read the data stream from the request?

Answer (score 0):

This is a minimal example of something I just got to work;

```
import requests
import shutil

def download(url):
    filename = url.split("/")[-1]
    path = "downloads/" + filename
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        with open(path, 'wb') as f:
            r.raw.decode_content = True
            shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, f)
    else:
        r.raise_for_status()

download('http://www.bocsar.nsw.gov.au/Documents/RCS-Annual/bluemountainslga.xlsx')
```

It reads the raw data from the request object and writes to a file where you want it to.

Comment: To anyone copy-pasting: Be aware that this script will fail silently in case the request fails.